# Restkit mapping dependency

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

Is it possible to make the mapping in restkit dependent on each other. I have the following JSON Structure:

```
{
    "IdList": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5",
        "6",
        "7",
        "8",
        "9",
        "10"
    ],
    “Persons”: [
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": “James”,
            "Description": “Tall”,
            "Items": [
                {
                    "Id": 1051,
                    "Name": “Hat”,
                    "Description": "",
                    “Accesories”: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have 2 response descriptors, in order to drill into the array IdList & Persons.

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[MappingProvider personsMapping] method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"Persons"statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[self addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

RKResponseDescriptor *IdsResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[MappingProvider IdsMapping] method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"IdList" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[self addResponseDescriptor:IdsResponseDescriptor];
```

My Mapping code:

```
+ (RKDynamicMapping *)IdsMapping {

    RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Ids" inManagedObjectStore:[[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] objectStore]];

    mapping.discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert = YES;

    [mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"theId"]];

    RKDynamicMapping *idsMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];

    [dynamicTableIdsMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:^RKObjectMapping *(id representation) {

        if (!representation) {

            return nil;

        } else {

            return mapping;

        }

        return nil;

    }];

    return dynamicTableIdsMapping;
}

+ (RKDynamicMapping *)personsMapping {

    RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Persons" inManagedObjectStore:[[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] objectStore]];

    mapping.assignsNilForMissingRelationships = YES;
    mapping.assignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = YES;
    mapping.discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert = YES;

    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
        @"Id": @"remoteID",
        @"Name": @"name"
    }];

    mapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"remoteID" ];

    [mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Items"
                                                                                   toKeyPath:@"products"
                                                                                 withMapping:[MappingProvider itemsMapping]]];
    RKDynamicMapping * dynamicMenuMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];


    [dynamicMenuMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:^RKObjectMapping *(id representation) {

      if (!representation) {

          return nil;

       } else {

            NSArray *categoryArray = [representation valueForKey:@"Items"];

            if (!categoryArray || !categoryArray.count) {

                return nil;

            } else {

                return mapping;

            }
        }

        return nil;

    }];

    return dynamicMenuMapping;
}
```

How would I manage to map the Persons array first and then the IdList? I only need to map the idList array if persons contains values. I want do this since the user is only presented for a new view, when data in Persons is present, and thereby also the idList. So if the persons array is empty, it is not nessasary to map the IdList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a single response descriptor with a nil key path. The mapping for that response descriptor would be a dynamic mapping which checked the contents and returned either a mapping which handled both sub-sections (so you would need a container class) or nil (to abandon the mapping process).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not exactly sure what you mean my container class? Can you please elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: To do what you ask you need 1 response descriptor. That would naturally map to 1 class type, but you have 2 (nested). So you would need to create a new class which had relationships to the other classes to facilitate the processing.

Comment: It may be simpler to change the server response or just delete some data after the mapping completes...