# separating entity mapping codes from domain model in RestKit

Tags: core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm following this tutorial for organizing code in rest kit

http://restkit-tutorials.com/code-organization-in-restkit-based-app/

I want to separate my domain model from restKit mappings.

so I added all my mapping to a class named mappingProvider.

```
RKEntityMapping *tableMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Table" inManagedObjectStore:[HAObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore];
tableMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"tableID"];
[tableMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                   @"ID":@"tableID",
                                                   @"TableNumber":@"tableNumber",
                                                   @"NumberOfChairs":@"numberOfChairs"}];
```

mapping provider needs a reference to ManagedObjectStore which I try to get from my custom subclass of `RKObjectManager` named `HAObjectManager`. 
`HAObjectManager` calls `[self setupResponseDescriptor]` which this method calls

```
RKResponseDescriptor *tableResponseDescriptors = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[MappingProvider tableMapping] method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"/api/table" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[self addResponseDescriptor:tableResponseDescriptors];
```

again this method calls `[MappingProvider tableMapping]` which again this calls `[HAObjectManager sharedManager]` to get managedObjectStore . as you see **this causes and infinite loop**.

does anyone know how should I solve it? 
for example a sharedInsatnce of coreData managedObjectStore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your initialisation order, which isn't necessarily trivial given your described structure. Most options are unpleasnt without doing significant rework.

A simple option for breaking the recurs ion is to add a parameter to `tableMapping` such that you can pass the object store as a parameter (so you don't need to call back to the partially initialised singleton to get it).

Comment: I saw someone used a shared instance of a custom class named coreDataManager to access managedObjecStore `[[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] objectStore]`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627332/restkit-mapping-dependency  do you know how should I implement it?  what is your scenario? how do you organize your code when using restKit?

Comment: That class would just manage the core data stack and nothing else. Personally, I use a data controller singleton which owns the core data stack, mappings and object managers - it abstracts the app from the outside world and presents an interface based on the app data model (no get / post / arbitrary data objects).

Comment: do you have any sample App I could use it? to see your code organization? I have stucked here for 1 day because I have to put all the code in the appDelegate. thats too bad!!

Comment: I would recommend to stick with what you have initially and add the parameter so you can pass the object store. Get it working first, then consider if you want to / need to refactor.